# loop thru array and group values into 4 arrays based on the values

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I need to group array results into 4 new arrays.
Trying to group each result into the appropriate array like:
top 25%
mid-top 25%
mid-low 25%
low 25%

THIS DOES NOT WORK but that's why I'm asking how to go about it.

```
$top = "70000";
$mid = "40000";
$low = "25000";

$resultsarray = array(100000,75000,55000,50000,20000,5000);
echo "Top 25%:";
   foreach ($resultsarray as $value) {
   if($value >= $top){
   echo $value;
   }
}

   echo "Mid Top 25%:";
   foreach ($resultsarray as $value) {
   if($value >= $mid && $value < $top){
   echo $value;
   }
}
```

and so on...

Comment: Right. My mistake.

Comment: What's wrong with it? It seems to work for me: http://ideone.com/hHwrUW

Comment: Your question says you want to put the values into new arrays, but your code just echoes them. Is that the problem? What part of adding to a new array are you having trouble with?

Comment: @CraigMartin was the error the `$numbers`? If it was, please accept the answer (with a green checkmark) if the solution is the one that worked for you so that future users know when reading this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_filter` will give you a smaller array based on the criteria you give.

```
$top = "70000";
$mid = "40000";
$low = "25000";

$resultsArray = array(100000,75000,55000,50000,20000,5000);

$top25 = array_filter($resultsArray, function ($value) use ($top) {
    return $value >= $top;
});

$midTop25 = array_filter($resultsArray, function ($value) use ($top, $mid) {
    return $value >= $mid && $value < $top;
});

$midLow25 = array_filter($resultsArray, function ($value) use ($mid, $low) {
    return $value > $low && $value < $mid;
});

$low25 = array_filter($resultsArray, function ($value) use ($low) {
    return $value <= $low;
});

function printNums(array $arr)
{
    return array_reduce($arr, function ($carry, $number) {
        return $carry .= $number .= " ";
    });
}

printf("Top 25%%: %s\n", printNums($top25));
printf("Mid-Top 25%%: %s\n", printNums($midTop25));
printf("Mid-Low 25%%: %s\n", printNums($midLow25));
printf("Low 25%%: %s\n", printNums($low25));
```

See it in action at https://3v4l.org/mGMOV

Comment: Thanks. That does work. Is there a way to do the same thing with different type of array like this: Array
(
    [751] => 2000
    [748] => 2500
    [752] => 3000
    [759] => 4500
    [750] => 5000
    [753] => 7600
)

Comment: If you are using PHP 5.6+, you can optionally filter by key or key & value. I wrote a blog post about this last year. http://ericpoe.com/blog/2015/07/08/php-array-filter-oddity/

Comment: Also, check out php.net's documentation on [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: What if the resultsArray is this:

Array ( [0] => User 751: 2000
[1] => User 748: 2500
[2] => User 752: 3000
[3] => User 759: 4500
[4] => User 750: 5000
[5] => User 753: 7600
)

array_filter by the users answer and echo the user id along with their answer.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this array notation. It looks like each array value is a string that contains the userID, a colon, and the score. If that's the case, then you will probably need to split the string into its component parts and run `array_filter` similar to above. Example: https://3v4l.org/1BNSU

Comment: The array notation was wrong. Here is the corrected array

$combinedarry = array_combine($userarray, $answersarray);
print_r($combinedarry);
this is my result of print_r($combinedarry);
example: 748 is the user and 748's answer is 2500
Array ( [748] => 2500 [753] => 7600 [759] => 4500 [750] => 5000 [751] => 2000 [752] => 3000 )

Comment: I believe that you have the tools to investigate this further. You can do it! If you get stuck, ask a new question and show what you have tried before.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$numbers` with `$resultsarray`. In your previous code, the `$numbers` array does not exist.

Let me know if that fixed it for you.

Comment: That was apparently just a copying error, he's corrected the question.